# How do I enter the commit message in this bash pop-up?

Tags: bash, git, vim, git-merge, git-bash

I want to **merge a remote repository to a new repository** on GitHub. I have tried the following bash commands:

```
git init
git commit --allow-empty -m "Initial dummy commit"
git remote add --fetch old_a <OldA repo URL>
git merge old_a/master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

After executing the last command, this screen pops up:

[image]

Here bash is asking me to **enter a commit message**. But typing appears to be prohibited everywhere except in the yellow line. Not only that, I can't even terminate this prompt if I want to go back to the command line. There seems ***no way to break out*** other than closing bash itself. So how do I proceed from here?

PS: I have already ***tried to change my default git editor*** to vim using the following commands:

```
git config --global core.editor vim
```

As well as,

```
export EDITOR="vim"
```

But both of these commands ***didn't work***.

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but: `git merge -m MESSAGE .....` allows you to provide the message on the command line.

Comment: BTW: Your screenshot looks like it is vi. Did you try any vi command? Can you switch to the vi command line using `:`?

Comment: The editor at the screen **is** `vim` so the last two commands work.

Comment: @user1934428 So can I skip the command 'git merge old_a/master --allow-unrelated-histories' ? As it is the one that is popping up this non-operational screen. The command 'vi -h' says my editor is Vim.

Comment: @phd But how do I commit the message in this pop-up?

Comment: If you want to do a merge, you have to issue a merge command; but if you use the `-m` option, the editor won't be shown. I don't understand what doing a `vi -h` on the command line would help in your case. I asked you whether entering a colon would show some reaction. I have set `EDITOR` to _nano_, and git presents me the _nano_ editor for editing the message.

Comment: @Rachit : If you set your editor explicitly to `vi`, I assume that you know how to operate vi. You say that you **can** type in the 'yellow line', which means that you are in input mode at this point, and hence 'breaking out' should be possible using Escape. What happens when you hit Escape?

Comment: It's not a popup, it's `vim` editor. Please spend an hour learning `vim`, at least run [`vimtutor`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_01.html#tutor). Later read [the docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_toc.html).

Comment: Or reconfigure `git` to use a different editor, one that you know.

Comment: @user1934428 If I directly hit the Esc key nothing happens. But as answered below by Bastiyan if I perform the following operation <Insert><Enter><my_message><Escape><:wq><Enter> then I can successfully come out of the pop-up & can proceed for further commands :)

Comment: @phd It's done. I did as suggested by Bastiyan and it did work out :) Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: @user1934428 Thank you very much for your help and time :))

Comment: Great, but why are you using **vi** for this job? You don't seem to be very familiar with this. You should have plenty of editors available, which are more self-explanatory.

Comment: @user1934428 Yes I am new to github/bash. I've checked on stackexchange on how to confirm the editor I'm using. Someone suggested to use 'vi -h' command. But thanks for your advice, I'll download & use vim from now onwards.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not an issue, all you need to do is

Press Insert Key and then Enter Key. This will allow you to type a message

Once you have done that Press Esace (Esc) then `:wq` to exit